# Specifying Android Market screensize in the Manifest

Tags: android, size, screen, manifest

Ok so I have my android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="" android:versionCode="6" android:versionName="1.2.3">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
<application android:label="" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:debuggable="true">
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INPUT_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ORIENTATION"/>
</manifest>
```

Where do I put in this:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

and is this the correct syntax to not show the application to people with fail phones on the market? I just want to show my app to people with a decent dpi screen as i guess it helps determine how fast their processor is, how much ram they might have etc.

Cheers guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it places on Just before "application" tag

Comment: Ok when I put it there I get this error in my console:       BUILD FAILED
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\main_rules.xml:310: null returned: 1

Total time: 0 seconds

Comment: ok sorted I specified it like this instead: <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" />  in the position you suggested. This worked! thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

It must be a manifest child.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/AndroidManifest.html

see the supportScreens section.